# How do I create a complex class property that can be bound to a WPF TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class with complex properties that are bound to my UI controls. The class can be converted at will to and from a string. How do I get that class to bind to a TextBox properly?

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(LatLongTypeConverter))]
public class LatLong : IComparable, IXmlSerializable
{
  .
  .
  .

  public override string ToString() {...}

  public static implicit operator LatLong(string L) {...}

  public static explicit operator string(LatLong L) {...}

  public class LatLongTypeConverter : TypeConverter
  {
    .
    .
    .
  }
}

public class City : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string _Name = "Chicago";
  private LatLong _Location = "41.52N 87.37W";

  public string Name
  {
    get => _Name;
    set { _Name = value; Notify(); }
  }

  public LatLong Location
  {
    get => _Location;
    set { _Location = value; Notify(); }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  public void Notify([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}"/>
```

How do I get the TextBlock to display "41.52N 87.37W" without using an IValueConverter? Currently, type conversion works perfectly in code, but when bound it just displays a blank field.

Comment: In XAML a type converter is only called (by the XAML processor) when you would assing a string to a non-string property - in your case LatLong. Then the XAML procesor would use the converter to convert the string to a LatLong instance. But since you are binding to the LatLong instance directly you have to use a IValueConverter or add a LatLong.DisplayValue property of type string to your type (and use this as binding source). The binding markup extension does not know how to convert the LatLong instance to a string instance. You must take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF only needs a `TextBlock` text to bind to a string, anything complex than that needs a converter to be bound directly. Which leaves two options, create a `IValueConverter` that takes a `LatLong` instance and returns a string, calling its implicit conversion for example, or do it in your code behind/viewmodel/whaterver you're binding to.

Here I'll show a very simple way to do the second option, by adding an extra property for WPF to bind to:

```
//New property for WPF to bind to, simply takes the full object and uses it's implicit string conversion
public string LocationString => (string)this.Location;

public LatLong Location
{
    get => _Location;
    //Here we notify changes of both properties, as one is calculated from the other
    set { _Location = value; Notify(); Notify("LocationString"); }
}
```

Then simply change the binding to the new property in the XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LocationString}"/>
```

Comment: You should consider to add the LocationString property to the LatLong type (as read-only property e.e.g with a private property Set(). This makes the LatLong type more conveniernt to (re)use.